# Save data to database via Spring Data repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am planning to store data from multiple tables which has one to many JPA relationship. I am creating my Repository interface which extends from JPARepository. My question is If I want to save a data on Many sides of relationship (in the below scenario it's Tour) then shall I do with TourRepository or PersonRespository?

On a similar note Is it ideal to create individual repository classes for every JPA entities where data need to be stored? or any better way with limited repository classes the data store to database can be achieved?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable{
...
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
private List<Tour> tours;
...



@Entity
@Table(name = "Tour")
public class Tour implements Serializable{
...
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
private Person person;
...
```

Comment: add cascade type on your @oneToMany, and use person to save both into database

Comment: As Gusti Arya said, adding proper cascade type will help here.  However, creating repository or not depends on something more high-level: If your `Tour` is something can be managed separately, you should have its own Repository.  I'd explicitly avoid creating repository only in the case of not creating child repository for parent-child relationship, for which the parent is the aggregate root (In Domain-Driven-Design terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two independent entities. `Person` can exist without `Tour` and `Tour` can exist without `Person`. So you should have two repositories - for Person and Tour to store their data independently:

```
Tour tour1 = new Tour("tour1");
tourRepo.save(tour1);

Person person1 = new Person("person1");
person1.addTour(tour1);
personRepo.save(person1);
```

You chose the bidirectional one-to-many association so you have to use a 'helper' method like `addTour` to link both entities:

```
public Person addTour(Tour tour) {

    tour.setPerson(this);
    this.tours.add(tour);
    return this;
}
```

Additional info: [Best Practices for Many-To-One and One-To-Many Association Mappings](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/)

Comment: this makes sense and on my requirement the many side of entity (in this example 'Tour') can't exists without the One side entity ('Person') which I can achieve from Person repository as you mentioned by adding addTour..method. However for find or delete an individual 'Tour' I still need a separate repository of ('TourRepository') I believe? I will go thru the link for more detail.

Comment: @SujitTripathy If you are going to delete/find `Tour` independently from `Person` you have to create TourRepo. An example of dependent entities can be: Order and its Lines - in this case we have to use only one OrderRepo.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cascade` to `tours`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Tour> tours;
```

When you save `person` object, his `tours` will be saved automatically.

By the way, in `Person` class, you should have an `addTour(...)` utilities method like this:

```
// Person.java

public void addTour(Tour tour){
    this.tours.add(tour);
    tour.setPerson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `CascadeType.ALL` on @OneToMany mapping in `Person` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Tour> tours;
```

And then create repository for person to save person object with the list of tours .

`CascadeType.ALL` means persistence will propagate all EntityManager operations like `PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH` to the relating entities.